# How do I show that these limits are equal?

Tags: calculus, limits

I found this exercise in the Michael Spivak's calculus book. The author asked to "interpret precisely" and then prove that these are equal:

$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\space\text{and}\space\lim_{h\to0}f(a+h)$$

I interpret the first one as "the limit of f at a", but I don't really know how to interpret the second one, and how to prove that they are equal.

Comment: "interpret precisely" means obtain one from another using definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that @zkutch is right, i.e. that you're expected to use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/(%CE%B5,_%CE%B4)-definition_of_limit#Precise_statement_and_related_statements). The first limit is the value of $L$, if it exists (in which case the triangle inequality implies it's unique), for which$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x(0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon).$$The second limit is the value of $L$, if it exists (in which case it's unique), for which$$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall h(0<|h|<\delta\implies|f(a+h)-L|<\varepsilon).$$These definitions are equivalent with the identification $x:=a+h$, which leads $x,\,h$ to have the same set of possible values, $\Bbb R\setminus\{a\}$.

Comment: I think that the question is similar to incremental ratio for the derivate. +1.